# Why is it not possible to combine child/descendant and grouping selector?

Tags: html, css

I cant quiet understand rules of constructing selectors that are made up of more than one selector.

I thought that its possible to have such selectors made up of more than one selector contain instances of other selectors that are also made up of more than one selector as part of them.And from what i have seen it is sometimes possible sometimes not.
For example here is HTML :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        div{
            border:solid red 10px;
            margin:10px;
        }

        p{
            background-color: orange;
        }

        div>div,p{
            border:solid black 7px;
            background-color: blue;
        }       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="small">AAA</div>
    <div>
        <p>AAA</p>
        <div class="small">AAA</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>AAA</p>
        <div class="small">AAA</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>AAA</p>
        <div class="small">AAA</div>
    </div>
    <div class="small">AAA</div>
    <p>AAA</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is it the case that as far as divs are concerned everything works as expected only divs that are children of  other divs are styled with third rule and rest are styled with first rule but for some reason paragraph gets styled according to third rule even thought its not child of div at all.

Then i thought maybe its because paragraph doesn't have any rule defined for it and then according to some rule i don't know about browser applies any style it finds on page to it so i decided to define a style specifically for paragraph with second rule.
But whats even more confusing is that for some reason not only third rule gets applied to p that is outside of div and not even its descendant but third rule also overrides second rule specifically defined for a paragraph.

This is very confusing to me i dont understand why is it the case that i cannot combine these selectors. From my understand up untill now first one should select all elements inside divs and then second one grouping selector should select all elements inside divs that are div and p type. But thats apparently not the case and i got it all wrong somehow. What are exactly the rules then for constructing selectors in css that are made up of more than one selector?

Comment: You want the [`:is()` "pseudo-class function"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is): `div > :is(div, p)`. Currently, it is parsed as the two selectors `div > div` and `p`, because of the [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors#selector_lists).

Comment: tl;dr change `div>div,p` to `div>div,div>p`

Answer (score 1):

The comma splits multiple selectors, so that you can apply the same rule sets to different selectors. Multiple selectors separated by a comma are not combined. The final ruleset you described is a selector for a `div` that is a child of a `div`, or a `p` tag. The ruleset can also be written as:

```css
div>div {
  border:solid black 7px;
  background-color: blue;
}

p {
  border:solid black 7px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Because CSS evaluates from top-down, the final rule takes priority.

For instance, if I were to give you the selector `div>p,a>div` this would evaluate to two selectors: `div>p` and `a>div`, not "a `div` tag that is a direct child of a `p` or `a` tag that is a direct child of a `div`."

Unfortunately, with CSS you must redefine the whole chain, so if you only want `p` tags that are direct descendants of `div` tags, you must use the selector `div>div, div>p`.

*Edit*: As [@DarrylNoakes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15261914/darryl-noakes) said, you can in fact use the [`:is()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) selector as kind of an "or" which is what you are looking for.

Comment: You don't have to "redefine the whole chain". You can use `:is()`.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Oh that's cool! I did not know this existed.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Nice alternative for `:is()`: the latest versions of major browsers support [CSS nesting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting).

Comment: @RuudHelderman You would have to duplicate the nested rulesets, though. Nesting allows nesting, which reduces duplication of *earlier parts of selectors* when later parts differ. `:is()` allows grouping, which reduces duplication of *rulesets*.

Comment: @DarrylNoakes Sorry, I don't follow. I was proposing `div { &>div, &>p { ... } }` as an alternative for `div > :is(div, p) { ... }`. As code duplication, I consider `&>` negligible.

Comment: Oh of course, a nested selector list. Yes, that works. And would allow you to preserve the specificities of the individual child components, as opposed to taking the highest (as with `:is()`. Just seems a bit of overkill in most cases :)